# Force flutter's TabBarView to fit to its content

Tags: flutter

How can I force `TabBarView` to take min height possible to fit its content?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(TabBarDemo());
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: Column(children: [
            Text('Header Widget'),
            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.directions_car),
                      Icon(Icons.directions_car),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
                  Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Text('Footer Widget')
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: TabBarView have an Expanded widget as a parent so it will take full space

Comment: Yes I know, I put `Expanded` to skip errors, What is alternative to force child to have its min height?

Comment: use Flexible instead of Expanded, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: The result of `Expanded` and `Flexible` is same

Answer (score -2):

Use BoxConstraint to restrict the height of TabBarView

```
Column(children: [
            Text('Header Widget'),
            Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxHeight: 100.0,
              ),
              child: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.directions_car),
                        Icon(Icons.directions_car),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
                  Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Text('Footer Widget')
          ]),
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: `maxHeight: 100.0` is not I want, I want something like  `maxHeight: auto`

Comment: so you want the inner column to be auto?

Comment: Yes, I want to make it auto, this is a minimal example, in real project I have complex child on my TabBarView

Comment: @WebMaster: why negative marking? could you explain?

Comment: I dont want explicitly set height constraint, As I don't know exact height, here is a minimal example, In real case I have a complex widget, I just wabt to fit content

Comment: Yes, you are right on your requirement, but this answer is also not wrong? right? with limited constraint. At least you cannot upvote the answer then do not downvote. This is not a bad one

Comment: I agree that your answer is not wrong, but it is not correct too. If you see my others questions, you can see I have very similar problem, every time someone answer me similar your answer, the easiest way, but not the right way, I tried this approach but for my usecase it works on some devices and not worka for some other devices, Because the hard coded height is not accurate height